# Prove that here $BE×DF$ is fixed

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, quadrilateral

We have a parallelogram namely $ABCD$. Then we draw a line from the vertex $A$ to:
1- Cross a point (namely $E$)on the side $BC$.
2- Cross a point  (namely $F$) along the side DC.
Now we must prove and show that here $BE×DF$ has a fixed and changeless amount if the line $AF$ cuts any other points as $E$ and $F$
I mean that we must prove that $BE×DF$ never changes, even if  $E$ and $F$ be different.
I think it's better to take a look here at this picture:
[image: MY DRAWING]

What I obtained was:
1- $$ \triangle ABE \thicksim \triangle CEF $$
2- $$ \frac{AB}{CF}= \frac{BE}{EC}= \frac{AE}{EF}$$
3- Thales's theorem works for $\triangle AFD$

4-  $$ \frac{CE}{AD}= \frac{FE}{FA}= \frac{FC}{FD}$$

Then we obtain that :
$$BE=\frac{AB×EC}{CF}=\frac{AE×EC}{EF}$$
$$DF=\frac{FD×EC}{AD}=\frac{AF×FC}{EF}$$
So any ideas to prove:
$$BE×DF=x$$ and $x$ is changeless?
 Note:C AND D MUST BE SWAPPED.

Comment: @greedoid  oh sorry i uploaded the pic but it was't in details. I will upload it now.

Comment: Your diagram is mislabeled. I think the points $C,D$ need to be swapped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original diagram had the points $C,D$ (perhaps accidentally) swapped.

Swapping them back,

[image]

we can argue as follows . . .

Let $x=AB,\;y=BC,\;$and let $t={\large{\frac{BE}{BC}}}$.

Thus, we have $BE=ty$, and $CE=(1-t)y$.

Since triangles $ABE$ and $FCE$ are similar, we get
$$CF=AB\left({\small{\frac{CE}{BE}}}\right)=x\left(\frac{1-t}{t}\right)$$
so
$$DF=x+CF=x+x\left(\frac{1-t}{t}\right)=\frac{x}{t}$$
hence
$$(BE)(DF)=(ty)\left(\frac{x}{t}\right)=xy$$
which is constant.

Comment: Oh I know thay but if we say $$BE\neq0$$

Comment: See my revised answer based on the corrected version of the diagram.

Comment: Thanks a lottttttt @quasi ! I don't know how I can really  thank you!.... yes I swapped C and D wrongly! But it is really a complete anwer!

Answer (score 0):

This is not true: $$ \triangle ABE \thicksim \triangle CEF $$
so your work is not correct.

Comment: but we can prove that! Look $AB$ and $CF$ are parallel and $BC$ and $AF$ are cornerways! @greedoid

Comment: would you explain why?

Comment: @greedois So if we prove that 4 angles are equal two by two then we say that $$ \triangle ABE \thicksim \triangle CEF $$ and i think that $$A and F$$ and $$B and C$$ and $$BEA and CEF$$ are equal degrees! Aren't they?

Comment: I measured them using a protractor and they were!

Comment: Can you prove your idea mathematically? I think they are!

Comment: when we draw a straight line from A to F and we draw another one from D to F , then my word is true. Isn't it?!

Comment: let's have a discussion about it. Are you ok with it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85758/discussion-between-user602338-and-greedoid).

Comment: Look I mean $\angle BCF$ is equal as $\angle ABC$